# Перегрузка операторов += и -=

Tags: c#, перегрузка-операторов

Для класа матрица нужно перегрузить операторы +,-, += и -=. С плюсом и минусом получилось, а вот с последними 2ма не всё так просто. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно их прегрузить для матрицы? Пробывал и так и сяк не выходит. Заранее благодарю за ответ)

```
class Matrix
    {
        private int n;
        private int[,] arr;

        public Matrix()
        {

        }

        public Matrix(int n)
        {
            this.n = n;
            arr = new int[this.n, this.n];
        }

        public int Len
        {
            get { return n; }
            set { if (value > 0) n = value; }
        }

        public int this[int i, int j]
        {
            get
            {
                return arr[i, j];
            }
            set
            {
                arr[i, j] = value;
            }
        }

        ////////////////////////////

        public void Input()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Input {0}:{1}", i + 1, j + 1);
                    arr[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }

        public void Output()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(arr[i, j] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        public static Matrix operator -(Matrix a,Matrix b)
        {
            Matrix result = new Matrix(a.Len);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Len; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < b.Len; j++)
                {
                    result[i, j] = a[i, j] - b[i, j];
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static Matrix operator -(Matrix a, int number)
        {
            Matrix result = new Matrix(a.Len);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Len; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < a.Len; j++)
                {
                    result[i, j] = a[i, j] - number;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static Matrix operator +(Matrix a, Matrix b)
        {
            Matrix result = new Matrix(a.Len);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Len; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < b.Len; j++)
                {
                    result[i, j] = a[i, j] + b[i, j];
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static Matrix operator +(Matrix a, int number)
        {
            Matrix result = new Matrix(a.Len);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Len; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < a.Len; j++)
                {
                    result[i, j] = a[i, j] + number;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static Matrix operator +=(Matrix a,  Matrix b)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Len; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < b.Len; j++)
                {
                     a[i, j]+=b[i,j];
                }
            }
            return a;
        }


        public static  Matrix operator -=(Matrix m)
        {
            Matrix result = new Matrix(m.Len);

            for (int i = 0; i < m.Len; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m.Len; j++)
                {
                    result[i, j] -= m[i, j];
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        /*public static Matrix operator -()
        {

        }*/

    }
```

Comment: Перегрузкой операторов особо не занимался, но. Не проще ли вызвать прямое сложение матриц, записав результат в операнд `a`? Т.е. `a = a + b`. Т.е. должен быть вызван Ваш перегруженный оператор сложения.

Comment: Перегрузить операторы `+=` и `-=` нельзя, так как они являются синтактическим сахаром и разворачиваются в полную конструкцию `x = x + (right)` и `x = x - (right)`. Следовательно после разворачивания уже будут работать с конструкцией `+` и `-` автоматически (как уже указали в ответе).

Comment: И как тогда быть?

Comment: Хм, а в питоне можно перегрузить)

Comment: @A1essandro это будет очень странно выглядеть, если операции `a = a + b` и `a += b` будут давать разные ответы. Скорее можно мозг сломать кому-нибудь такими конструкциями.

Comment: Да вы правы) Спасибо

Comment: Я с Вами полностью согласен. Но есть `__iadd__()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В перегрузке += и -= нет необходимости т.к. как это синтаксический сахар для операций +,-.  И их вы получаете автоматически при перегрузке операций +,-.
https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level6/6_4.php

Comment: Я немного не  понял += и -= перегрузить впринципе нельзя или нет необходимости тк.  a=a+b заменяет a+=b??

Comment: Операторы += и -= не перегружаются, т.к. это не самостоятельные операторы, а языковые конструкции предназначенные для удобства использования операций +,-.  Если Вы хотите использовать в своей программе конструкции +=и -= то Вам достаточно перегрузить операторы + и -. И после этого можете автоматически использовать операторы +=, -=.

Comment: Спасибо вам) Теперь буду знать:)